# Insert, select and insert in same command

Tags: c#, sql-server

Currently i'm using the following C# code to insert rows into a database

```
int result = 0;
            using (SqlConnection connect = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {                    
                string insertQuery = @"Insert Into Conversions (CID, Source, Destination, Packages, CreatedBy, SourceID) 
            SELECT @CID, @Source, @Destination, @Packages, @CreatedBy, @SourceID";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, connect);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CID", cidBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Source", sourceSoftwareBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Destination", destinationSoftwareBox.Text);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("Packages", packagesBox.Text);                    
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("CreatedBy", Environment.UserName);
                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("SourceID", sourceID.sourceID);
                connect.Open();
                result = Convert.ToInt32(command.ExecuteScalar());
            }
```

I have another table called `HistoricalData` with the following columns:
`Id`, `Status`, `Comments`, `Date`

I want to be able to Insert into the `Conversions` table, select the `Id` that was just auto created from the insert and use that `Id` in a second insert into the `HistoricalData` table.  Can I do this with some sort of SQL magic?

Comment: You can do that using the OUTPUT clause. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx You might also want to read this article about AddWithValue. http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/

Comment: `SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY() AS [SCOPE_IDENTITY];` you will get last inserted id from `Conversions` table then you can insert your `HistoricalData` table just normal `INSERT`  statement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`OUTPUT`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177564.aspx) clause to insert directly into the 2nd table. Your SQL would be something like:

```
INSERT Conversions (CID, Source, Destination, Packages, CreatedBy, SourceID)
OUTPUT inserted.ID, @Status, @Comments, GETDATE()
    INTO HistoricalData (ID, Status, Comments, Date)
VALUES (@CID, @Source, @Destination, @Packages, @CreatedBy, @SourceID);
```

This won't work however if there is a foreign key relationship between the two tables. In some cases I would advise simply using the output clause to insert into a temp table before inserting to the child table, but since you are only inserting a single row and only accessing the identity field, you could just use [`SCOPE_IDENTITY()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms190315.aspx):

```
INSERT Conversions (CID, Source, Destination, Packages, CreatedBy, SourceID)
VALUES (@CID, @Source, @Destination, @Packages, @CreatedBy, @SourceID); 

INSERT HistoricalData (ID, Status, Comments, Date)
VALUES (SCOPE_IDENTITY(), @Status, @Comments, GETDATE());
```

*N.B. In both instances I was unsure of what you would want to add as `Status`, `Comment`, and `Date`, so have used variables and `GETDATE()`, you may need to adjust this.*

*Another note, I have switched from a `SELECT` with no `FROM` to the `VALUES` constructor for the insert, mostly out of second nature when rewriting the queries. There is no difference in the two methods, although I do find using `VALUES` displays intent better, it shows clearly nothing is being selected.*

Answer (score 1):

If your database in question supports stored procedures i would definitely go that way. Create a stored procedure with required parameters. Create your SqlCommand like this:

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("MyStoredProcedureName", connect);
command.CommandType=CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

Pass your parameters like in your current code.
Your database stored procedure would look something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MyStoredProcedureName 
@CID bigint,
..... all params
    AS
    BEGIN
   DECLARE @myNewID bigint
SET NOCOUNT ON;

        Insert Into Conversions (CID, Source, Destination, Packages, CreatedBy, SourceID) VALUES (@CID, @Source, @Destination, @Packages, @CreatedBy, @SourceID)
    SET @myNewID=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
    -- Now you can insert what you want where you want
    INSERT INTO  HistoricalData (Column list...) (Values list ... @myNewID)
    END
```

If you are not using Entity Framework or something like this it is best to keep database code separate from rest of your code. So when you change table names/column names or any change in database structure you don't have to change your code. Just change the database part and your stored procedures.